# TypeError: fetch is not a function with @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure

I am unable to use the @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth to authenticate (or even see response errors) using `loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse`. The following code segment:

```
import * as msRestNodeAuth from "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth";
msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
    clientID,
    clientSecret,
    tenantID
  ).then((r) => console.log("Authenticated")).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
    throw e;
  });
```

Prints `TypeError: fetch is not a function` to the console. I'm using the package in node 12.9.1 with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is server-side code, as you are working with Node.JS. Do take note that the native [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API is only available on browsers, thus it can only be used within the browser `window` global. However, it is polyfillable through packages such as [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) and [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). Therefore, you should install and configure either of the packages on your project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems odd to have to polyfill a browser API, since the package (maintained by Azure) is documented to be compatible with Node. I tried using a polyfill anyway and ended up with another TypeError related to the package internals...

Comment: @natmegs yes, you need to some configuration so that TS won't complain about it. What is the error anyways?

Comment: with the node-fetch polyfill the error was `TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal`